# Stopping media player

Tags: java, android

So I'm making sound application for android and I am stuck at 1 little problem.

When I click on button1, it plays sound. That part is working good, but I want my app to stop current media player upon clicking on button2, and play Button 2 sound.

```
  final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kalas);

  ImageButton sound1=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sound1);
  sound1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.pause();
            mp.seekTo(0);
        }
        else {

            mp.start();

        }

    }
});
```

Comment: show us the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new ImageButton and set `onClickListener` to the button and check if it is playing and then stop the mediaPlayer by `mp.stop();`

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kalas); 
ImageButton sound1=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sound1); 
ImageButton sound2=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sound2); 

sound1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override public void onClick(View v) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        if (mp.isPlaying()) { 
            mp.pause(); 
            mp.seekTo(0); 
        } 
        else { 
            mp.start(); 
        } 
    } 
}); 

sound2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override public void onClick(View v) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        if (mp.isPlaying()) { 
            mp.stop
        } 

    } 
});
```

Comment: Yea this so far is working, but it won't play sound linked to that button.

Answer (score 2):

```
ImageButton sound2=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sound2); 

sound2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
@Override public void onClick(View v) { 
// TODO Auto-generated method stub 
if (mp.isPlaying()) { 
  mp.pause(); 
  mp.seekTo(0); 
} 
mp.start();  
} 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution with complete code :)

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kalas);

  ImageButton sound1=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sound1);
  sound1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.pause();
            mp.seekTo(0);
        }
        else {

            mp.start();

        }

    }
});

  ImageButton sound2=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sound2);
  sound2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.pause();
            mp.seekTo(0);
        }
        else {

            mp.start();

        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Call First When you play song. Try This may be help you

```
 public MediaPlayer StopMediaPlayer(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
    return mediaPlayer;
}
```